# Get values from join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `user` and `details` table. I want to display the details table in a table format.

`user` table Structure is:

[image]

`details` Table Structure is:

[image]

Result table Structure is:
[image]

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT A.*,B.name,C.name as Interviewer 
FROM exitdetail_hrms A
  LEFT JOIN hh_tbl_user B ON A.emp_id=B.sno 
  JOIN hh_tbl_user C
WHERE A.emp_id='12' AND C.sno='13'
```

But I didn't get exact answer..kindly help me on this..

Thanking You..

Comment: You miss the `ON` clause on th join to table C

Comment: if i put on condition i will not get my result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, because you table description does not match the SQL you used, but i think the following SQL should solve your problem:

```
SELECT A.*,B.name,C.name as Interviewer 
FROM exitdetail_hrms A
  LEFT JOIN hh_tbl_user B ON A.emp_id=B.s_no 
  LEFT JOIN hh_tbl_user C ON A.interviewed = C.s_no
WHERE A.emp_id='12' AND C.sno='13'
```